# Lighting Aura Controller - If Then on checkbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, conditional

I cannot figure out the correct syntax to evaluate a checkbox field on my component. I have to believe I have the syntax wrong because the IF statement is being executed even though the checkbox is empty.

Component Field:

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="vbChoice" fieldName="Voluntary_Benefits__c" />
```

Controller;

```
handleSuccess: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var params = event.getParams();
        cmp.set('v.recordId', params.response.id);
        cmp.set('v.showSpinner', false);
        cmp.set('v.saved', true);

        var inputCmp = component.find("vbChoice").get("v.value");

        //Only navigate to the Benefit page if VB was selected. 
        if(inputCmp == 'true') {
            var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            navEvt.setParams({
                "recordId": params.response.id,
                "slideDevName": "related"
            });

            navEvt.fire();
        } else {
            var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
        }

    },
```

Comment: Hello Matt, what is value of inputCmp as you are comparing like string instead of boolean value?

Comment: I have tried if(inputCmp == TRUE) and if(inputCmp) and nothing seems to work.

Comment: so what is value of inputCmp?

Comment: i think u r using `lightning:recordeditform`  so why don't you get the latest value from `params.response` for `Voluntary_Benefits__c` like `params.response.Voluntary_Benefits__c`

Comment: Are there 2 components with same id `vbChoice` ? or something is in loop?

Comment: @sdandamud1 I tried your suggestion but it keeps evaluating as false every time.

Comment: if(params.response.Voluntary_Benefits__c) {

Comment: @PranayJaiswal said, your issue in with `id` can you post your whole component code

Answer (score 0):

You should try with below code to get property value and adding conditional logic.

```
     var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");
     var field = 'Voluntary_Benefits__c';
     if (eventFields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
         if ( !eventFields.Voluntary_Benefits__c) { 
             event.preventDefault();           
             var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
             dismissActionPanel.fire();
         }
         else
         {
             var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
             navEvt.setParams({
                 "recordId": params.response.id,
                 "slideDevName": "related"
             });
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. The original sample code I got from Salesforce uses the abbreviation cmp instead of the word component. This was the issue with my orignal attempts to access the value.

Here is the functioning code:

```
handleSuccess: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var params = event.getParams();
        cmp.set('v.recordId', params.response.id);
        cmp.set('v.showSpinner', false);
        cmp.set('v.saved', true);

        //Only navigate to the Benefit page if VB was selected. 
        if(cmp.find("vbChoice").get("v.value")) {
            var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            navEvt.setParams({
                "recordId": params.response.id,
                "slideDevName": "related"
            });

            navEvt.fire();
        } else {
            var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
        }

    },
```